# Printing to Dymo Labelmaker with Python on OS X

Tags: python, xml, dymo

Part of my job is to print several hundred labels per day with a Dymo labelwriter. We use macOS for everything, and installing Windows is out of the question as it would break tons of workflow. We have a template file that I can modify using Python's xml.etree module. How would I print the labels to our labelwriter using solely Python? I've read up on using `os.system` to send the data straight to the printer, but I'm not sure how that would work with an XML file and a labelwriter, which seems incredibly proprietary. I don't mind using other languages or APIs as long as they're easy to explain to the non-technical people in the office. Also open to using AppleScript.

Comment: hi, did you find any solution?